# What is ++ operator doing in Python?

Tags: python

Python doesn't support C-style `++a` increment but, to my surprise, it doesn't complain either leading to me being temporarily baffled as to why my loop wasn't working.

Trying a few things (having first initialised with `a=0`) I find that `a++` and `a--` produce a syntax error, but `++a` doesn't. While `--a` produces a syntax error in Python 3.3 but not in Python 2.7.

What's going on? Why doesn't `++a` give an error? Why does `--a` not give an error in 2.7 but does give an error in 3.3?

Comment: I don't have 3.3 at hand, what error are you getting?

Comment: Apparently I was being some kind of muppet because when I try it again it works fine.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Take a look at this console session:

```
>>> a = 10
>>> ++a
10
>>> +a
10
>>> -a
-10
>>> --a
10
```

Basically, `++a == +(+(a))`, and `--a == -(-(a))`. This one's to hit the concept home (and for fun):

```
>>> ++++++++++a
10
```

The following code sample serves no purpose other than to show you how much fun python is:

```
>>> +-+-+a
10
```

With something like this, you can make ASCII art that *runs*.

If you want to increment you do it like so: `a += 1`. And `--a` works in [Python 2 and 3](http://ideone.com/TQFCqv).

Comment: @glglgl hi5 man. And rubyists say ruby gets to have all the fun :P

Answer (score 12):

Short answer: it calls the `__pos__` method twice. Consider for instance:

```
>>> class A(object):
...     def __init__(self, x):
...         self.x = x
...     def __pos__(self):
...         return A(2 * self.x)
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return 'A(%s)' % self.x
... 
>>> a = A(1)
>>> a
A(1)
>>> +a
A(2)
>>> ++a
A(4)
>>> +++a
A(8)
```

For integers, as `+x` returns `x`, it does basically nothing.

Answer (score 0):

No, in  Python (both 2.x and 3.x), using  `++var` will return the same value of the variable as it was previously, provided that the variable's value was actually a number. And using `var++` will raise an exception.

Also, in Python the `++var` operation's behavior is not as same as some other languages, like PHP, JS, C++, where `++var` actually means that you're to increment the variable's value by 1. But in Python, to increment, you must use something like `var = var + 1` or `var += 1` or it will not work.